# How to reuse a webview in two activities?

Tags: android

i am using a webview to load some content in one activity, and then in another activity i would like to reuse this same view. But when i try to reuse it, the content from the previous activity is still inside of the webview and the content never loads. How do i get around this to reuse the webview?

Comment: you need to reuse the android layout.xml which contain webview ,or you need  the same layout loaded in one activity need to used in other without setting any new content in that activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `WebView.clearView()` or `WebView.reload()` in `onStart()` of your activities

Answer (score 2):

Views were not designed to be shared between activities.  Why do you need to use the same webview in two activities?  Why can't each activity have it's own view?

Comment: Well, that's totally rubbish idea! Whatever happened to OO development? Android is written in JAVA after all - I know why - Android is all about why write 5 lines of code when you can write 500 lines of code and introduce loads more overhead in terms of app size, coding time and increase potential for bugs!

Comment: You guys are probably misunderstanding each other: @jamesw wants to reuse the **code** which is perfectly valid, while spatulamania is saying **instances of Views in memory** were not designed to be shared. So you're both correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is little different. It pivots around couple of things.

WebViews can be created with application context.
There is something called MutableContextWrapper, we can flip the underlying context inside it.
So, we create the web view in the pool with mutable context wrapper with appContext and when an activity context asks for it, we flip the context and return it. We flip the context to appContext when we return the webView back.

You can see a detailed post here along with the code.
https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/clean-android-webview-caching-9b871b3579f3